# Error after installing pip tensorflow-gpu with cuda 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I want to use only the pip version of tensorflow as in conda version if tensorflow-gpu gets error code runs on cpu which is undesirable.

After installing cuda 10 and cudnn for ubuntu 18.0.4 when I import tensorflow it gives me the following error.

PS: I purged everything related to cuda and Nvidia and then installed the new Cuda 10.

> Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:16:44) 
>   [GCC 7.3.0] on linux
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> >>> import tensorflow
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/home/purav/anaconda3/envs/purav/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I don't know why this error is there I don't have cuda verison 9

Comment: The error is **because** you don't have CUDA 9. Install it

Comment: But I have Ubuntu 18.0.4 and Cuda 9 does not support this Ubuntu version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current stable version of `tensorflow-gpu` available through pip is v1.12 which is built against CUDA 9.0. If you look at issue number [22706](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22706) of tensorflow github repository, the official binaries of upcoming tensorflow-gpu v1.13 are expected to be built against CUDA 10.

As of 23 January 2019, the [rc0 version of tensorflow-gpu v1.13](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.13.0-rc0) has been released which has been built against CUDA 10. It can be installed using `pip` by specifying the version as follows:

> pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.0rc0

Since CUDA 9 has been replaced with CUDA 10 in your system, the default tensorflow-gpu code is failing because it is version 1.12 and expecting CUDA 9 binaries to be present in the system. So currently, if you want to use tensorflow with CUDA 10, then the quickest solution is to upgrade your tensorflow version as specified above.

Comment: Using this I am able to import tensorflow but when I try to run my code it gives error of convolution algorithm not found would this be because of the version change of tensorflow because it works fine on my other PC which is perfectly configured with Cuda and Cudnn 9.0 with tesnorflow-gpu v1.12

Comment: The convolution algorithm error may be due to the incorrect cuDNN version. Which version did you have previously and which one do you have currently?

Comment: Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.2.1 but source was compiled with: 7.4.2. This is the error I am getting but installed the latest cudnn which is: 
libcudnn7_7.4.2.24-1+cuda10.0_amd64.deb

and I did not have any other version before this one

Comment: @PuravZumkhawala... Then maybe try installing cuDNN v7.4.2.

Comment: I Actually had a cuda version in an anaconda environment which was requiring the 9.0 so file I removed everything cuda,cudnn and anacaonda and then installed the specified cuda version with respective cudnn which worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you haven't fully satisfied the TensorFlow GPU requirements.
The full list is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) on the TF website.


The main cause of your error seems that you don't have the [CUDA toolkit 9.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone) configured well with the [cuDNN SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) please note you need a version greater or equal to 7.2 and add it to your system path.

Answer (score 0):

I am running python 3.7 and was able to install tensorflow with cuda 10 by running :

```
 pip install --no-cache-dir https://github.com/evdcush/TensorFlow-wheels/releases/download/tf-1.12.0-py37-gpu-10.0/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Does this allow you to use Gpu ? as when run this  command only tensorflow gets installed not tensorflow-gpu

Comment: yes, I ran this to set up a rtx 2070 GPU with CUDA  10, the person who made this has laid out more details at github.com/evdcush/TensorFlow-wheels

Comment: you might want to make sure that tensorflow is completely uninstalled from your system and re-running the command just in case this was a pre-existing version

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you install different versions of Tensorflow, Cuda and Cudnn
you need to install based on this link : [Tensorflow GPU list](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)

if you want to install TensorFlow proper way you can check my blog on this [Blog Link](https://medium.com/@vkmauryavk/how-to-install-the-correct-cuda-version-for-tensorflow-e906cc39bf9d)